# Print decimal integer

Tags: c, strings, integer, x86, nasm

This is an x86-64 Linux program to print a non-negative decimal integer. I would appreciate any simple optimizations for size and readability. I am aware that division by a constant is usually done by multiplication by the magic constant reciprocal, but I used `div` here for simplicity.

```
; nasm -f elf64 print_dec.asm && ld print_dec.o -o print_dec
global _start

section .text

; print non-negative decimal integer in rdi
print_dec:              
    push    rbp         ; callee-saved 
    mov     rbp, rsp    ; save sp

    mov     rcx, 10     ; divisor base
    mov     rax, rdi    ; dividend from arg0
    
L1:
    xor     rdx, rdx    ; zero upper dividend
    div     rcx         ; unsigned divide rdx:rax by rcx
                        ; rax := quotient, rdx := remainder
    add     rdx, '0'    ; convert digit to ASCII
    push    rdx         ; push remainder digit
    cmp     rax, 0       
    jne     L1          ; do while (rax != 0)

L2:
    mov     rax, 1      ; call number for write
    mov     rdi, 1      ; write to stdout (fd=1)
    mov     rsi, rsp    ; use char on stack
    mov     rdx, 1      ; write 1 char
    syscall
    
    add     rsp, 8      ; "pop" stack 
    cmp     rbp, rsp    ; do while (stack still has digits)
    jne     L2 

    pop     rbp
    ret

_start:
    mov     rdi, 1234   ; int to print
    call    print_dec

    mov     eax, 60     ; exit call number
    xor     rdi, rdi    ; exit code 0
    syscall
```

Before I wrote the code, I wrote my simple stack-based algorithm (pretty much the only way I think you could write it) in C first and cheated a bit by looking at the [godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/zcqhnqhWK). But I don't know how to force the compiler to use `push` and `pop` as I did because it just does indirect addressing like `mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8+rbx*8], rdx`. So the "stack" is implemented in C and not the x86 stack. If there is a way to, please let me know.

```c
// print non-negative integer in decimal
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

void print_dec(ull x)
{

    ull stack[20];

    ull sp = 0; // not actual x86 sp
    ull bp = sp;
    ull d;

    do // run at least once to print 0
    {
        d = x % 10; 
        stack[sp++] = d + '0'; // push
        x /= 10;
    } while (x);

    do 
    {
        d = stack[--sp]; // pop
        putc(d, stdout);
    } while (sp != bp);
}

int main() 
{
    print_dec(1234);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That stack on the stack is (ironically?) an unusual technique, but OK.

Various 64-bit instructions can be replaced with an equivalent 32-bit instruction, which typically makes them smaller.

- `mov rcx, 10` can be `mov ecx, 10`
- `xor rdx, rdx` can be `xor edx, edx`
- In this context, `add rdx, '0'` can be `add edx, '0'`, since `rdx` always has a small value here
- `mov rax, 1` can be `mov eax, 1` etc

For `mov rcx, 10` and similar instructions, that saves 2 bytes each (the REX prefix, but also using a different opcode that doesn't need a Mod/RM byte). The other instructions just lose their REX prefix and become 1 byte smaller.

Comparison to zero can be simplified:

> ```
> cmp     rax, 0       
> jne     L1
> ```

Can be:

```
test    rax, rax     
jne     L1
```

That only saves one byte.

Before the syscall that writes the byte, there are 3 separate loads of the value 1, two of them can be replaced with a mov between registers, making them 3 bytes smaller each. These days that [probably doesn't cost more time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342/555045) either, although that wouldn't have been relevant relative to the huge cost of a syscall anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious why the compiler will use a local array on the stack but not push/pop.

Comment: @qwr compilers have never done that kind of locally-unbalanced stack manipulation[citation needed] but it makes even less sense now since with the SysV AMD64 ABI it is almost always an ABI violation to do it (and it definitely requires a frame pointer which is typically avoided). You can get away with it here, probably.

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate any simple optimizations for size and readability.

**Memory reduction**

Rather than `ull stack[20];`, only a byte array is needed.

**Avoid UB**

The magic number 20 is insufficient when `ull/unsigned long long` is more than 64-bits. C only requires that type to be *at least* 64-bit.

An alternative is to scale `stack[]` size by the bit-width of `ull`.

```
// Size to encode an unsigned type as a "decimal" string: value_bit_with*log2(10) + 1
#define LOG2_10_N  28
#define LOG2_10_D  93
#define ULL_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE (sizeof(ull)*CHAR_BIT*LOG2_10_N/LOG2_10_D + 1)
```

**One output call**

Rather than form the digits forwards in `stack[]`, save them starting from the end of `stack[]` and then print once.

```
unsigned char stack[ULL_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE + 1];  // +1 for a string
unsigned sp = ULL_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE;
stack[ULL_DECIMAL_TEXT_SIZE] = 0;

do {
    stack[--sp] = (int)(x % 10) + '0'; // push
    x /= 10;
} while (x);

fputs(stack + sp, stdout);
```

Comment: You are right about me assuming long long would only be 64 bit, which I can document.  I don't know if the fputs call would work in assembly unless there was a way to push just bytes onto the x86 stack? I like the symmetry of push/pop anyhow.

Comment: @qwr Rather than document assuming `long long` would only be 64 bit, use `typedef uint64_t ull;` instead of `unsigned long long` (or adjust `stack[]` as answered).